# Output repeater field in a table

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to output my `acf 5` [repeater field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) in a table.

I use the following code:

```
   <?php
            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
            if (have_rows('founder')):
?>
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Founders</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Image</th>
               <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
            <?php
                // loop through the rows of data
                while (have_rows('founder')):
                    the_row(); ?>
            <tr>
               <td> <img src="<?php the_sub_field('founder_img'); ?>"></img> </td>
               <td><?php echo get_sub_field('firstname'); ?> &nbsp; <?php the_sub_field('lastname'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                endwhile; ?>
   </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

However, even though I have in my backend all the fields filled I get the following output:

[image]

The html output looks like the following:

```
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Founders</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Image</th>
               <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
                        <tr>
               <td> <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/no-avai.jpg"> </td>
               <td>test &nbsp; test</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
               <td> <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/no-avai.jpg"> </td>
               <td>Firstname &nbsp; Lastname</td>
            </tr>
               </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Any suggestion what I am doing from?

Comment: Hm, tricky without seeing how the fields are setup in WP - are your fields set up properly? (founder_img is a sub field of founder etc.)

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same thing. Either there is a typo, or mapping is off. The code organization seems solid.

Comment: try to see if you are getting your fields - you can just paste this before your table - or at least outside your while-loop : echo '<pre>' . var_export(get_fields(), true) . '</pre>';

Comment: This will give you a nice overview of what the code can fetch and which fields the data is in.